# Why is Optional final?

Tags: java, option-type

It's pretty clear that `Optional<T>` has to be immutable and subclassing it in user code would be kind of painful. But anyway what is the reason it declared final? We cannot subclass it anyway because all constructors are declared as private.

```
private Optional(T value) {
    this.value = Objects.requireNonNull(value);
}

private Optional() {
    this.value = null;
}
```

Without final class declaration it would look like `Option` in `scala` which is `sealed` and actually subclassed with `Some` and `None`.

I don't see any reason of finalizing the class. It might be convinient to have some `private static` subclasses inside the `Optional` itself.

Comment: Good coding practice ?

Comment: @GCP What about `sealed abstract class Option` in scala?

Comment: @St.Antario I have no experience with Scala as of yet.

Comment: What does the suggested duplicate miss?

Comment: @OliverCharlesworth `private` constructors are not enough to prevent subclassing outside of the class itself?

Comment: @St.Antario maybe you want to ask that as a separate question.

Comment: It's may be difficult to answer this question authoritatively, then - given that has it to be behaviourally final, there seems to be no reason to **not** declare it `final` - evidently the authors have no need for inner subclasses.

Comment: @OliverCharlesworth Have to agree... Sounds reasonble.

Comment: I'm not sure, but perhaps the compiler can take advantage of the finality of the class for optimisation...